# What is the relationship between seed hash and mix hash in mining?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

Miner receives seed hash and sends back mix hash. I understand that mix hash is basically a random slice of DAG, is this correct?

But more importantly, how does geth check that mix hash is correct? From studying geth I can see that it inserts it into the block template and then tries to hash it with nonce. But could not I pick any mix hash?

Comment: The EthHash [spec](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) explains this in detal

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I did read that but I am not sure about it.

Comment: I am not saying that it does not explain it, just that I did not understand it from the wiki.

Comment: This is actually an excellent question. I can identify the line where this is checked in the [python client](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/ethpow.py#L72), for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EthHash algorithm works by defining two critical structures:

- A 16 MB cache, which is generated from a seed, which is changed every epoch. Every node (including light clients) generates this cache and stores it.
- A 1 GB DAG, which is generated from the cache in such a way that each part of the DAG depends on a small number of pseudo-randomly chosen elements from the cache.

You are correct in that the mix hash is essentially generated from a collection of pseudo-random pieces of the DAG, but it is important to note that these pieces are chosen in a deterministic way that depends only on the block header (not including the mixhash) and the nonce.

In order to be able to mine quickly, miners pregenerate the full DAG and store it in memory, so that lookups are fast, because the miner needs to try millions of nonces in order to find a successful one.

Each round of the algorithm only requires 64 lookups to the DAG, however. This means that given a nonce, a non-mining client can use the cache to generate only the small portion of the DAG that is actually used.

You can see the line of code in Geth which performs the difficulty check during block verification [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/chain_pow.go#L68), which calls [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/pow/dagger/dagger.go#L91) code, which then computes the actual mixhash using [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/pow/dagger/dagger.go#L151) function.

As for the second (and IMO more interesting) part of your question, I can't seem to find where Geth checks the mixhash generated from the nonce against the one in the block header. I may be missing something, and I'll get edit this answer later

Comment: So using the 16MB cache only you can verify the mix hash without having the full dag?

Comment: Yes, you use the cache to generate only the parts of the DAG that you need.

Comment: OK, Marked as accepted, if you happen to stumble upon the geth mixhash check please edit...